# C# WPF XAML - DataGrid making 2 cols instead of 1

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am making a DataGrid to show the avaliable pages to open.

I can get the names from the collection but it also shows the name length for some reason.  I only have 1 column!

[image: Outcome]

```
            <DataGrid Name="Menu"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Background="Gray"
                      HeadersVisibility="None"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding pages}"
                      ColumnWidth="*"
                      CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="na" Binding="{Binding}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

What is going on?!

Comment: Add `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` to the DataGrid element.

Comment: Doh!  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Add it as an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Meh, it's a duplicate .Glad we got it resolved.